# Python: Concat values of all rows in single row in all columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to concat all the values in the rows from all columns. See below examples for more details.

Input --->

```
col_1 col_2   
1      a  
2      b  
3      c  
4      d
```

Output----->

```
col_1     col_2  
1_2_3_4   a_b_c_d
```

Is it possible to perform such operation using pandas in python?

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` with `join` ,after convert all value to `string` type

```
s=df.astype(str).apply('_'.join).to_frame(0).T
s
Out[247]: 
     col_1    col_2
0  1_2_3_4  a_b_c_d
```